# How to stop running function in windows application which is using WCF persession service in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I want to stop running function in middle if UI is closed. As I have two part of windows application One is server and second is Client. I am calling a function of server by WCF service which is PerSession from client UI. On server side, function does call the other services which are not PerSession, call some Stored Procedure and call some static functions. Is there any way to stop all running functionality, SP's whenenver user close the UI.

Comment: The service won't know the UI is closed.   You could have the client send a request to the service to stop the process(es) it's running via the OnClosing event, but then you run the possibility of having data in an unstable or corrupt state.

Comment: I have send request at server side and dispose the service. But it did not work. Stored procedure and static function do not stop.

Comment: The stored procedures are being run on the database.  The  web service has no control over that.  Which is why I said you have the possibility of having data in an unstable or corrupt state.